# A morphism of monads that doesn't preserve thunkability?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Recall that for a monad $(T,\eta,\mu)$ on a category $C$, the Kleisli category $C_T$ has as objects the objects of $C$ and as morphisms $C_T(x,y) = C(x,T y)$.  A morphism $f\in C_T(x,y) = C(x,T y)$ is said to be *thunkable* if $T\eta \circ f = T f \circ \eta$ (in $C$), or equivalently $T \eta \circ f = \eta T \circ f$.  (The name comes from viewing Kleisli categories as semantics for call-by-value programming languages, see e.g. the references [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thunk-force+category).)

Every morphism in the image of the free functor $F:C\to C_T$ is thunkable, and the converse holds if $\eta$ is the equalizer of $\eta T$ and $T \eta$.  I am told that every nontrivial monad on $\mathrm{Set}$ satisfies this condition.

If $T_1\to T_2$ is a morphism of monads on $C$, there is an induced functor $C_{T_1} \to C_{T_2}$.  My question is: is there a morphism of monads such that this induced functor does *not* preserve thunkability?  The above remark shows that if so, $C$ cannot be $\mathrm{Set}$.

Comment: Is it trivial to show that every nontrivial monad on Set satisfies the condition?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I don't know, I haven't tried.

Comment: (BTW there are two "trivial" monads on Set: one is constant at 1, the other is constant at 1 everywhere except it sends 0 to 0.)